# How to create one form from multiple unassociated (Not Nested) models in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 with postgres. Each model has an input form where users input parameters. Those parameters are then used to search a table. Each model has its own parameters unrelated to the others and own table to search. All the models then return a value from their respective tables. The models and their associated forms work just stand alone (I enter my parameters in model 1, and it searches the table for model 1 and returns the answer).

I am trying to create a series of pages that allow me to combine the models. For example, I want pages where a user can enter information in all 3 models, pages with just 2 of the 3 models, or perhaps even pages with two of the same model and a third different one. What is the best way to do this?

I have tried nested_attributes but am not sure it applies because I do not have associations. Am I missing something with that function that does allow it work in this use case? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a somewhat contrived example of a form containing several models, without nesting:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "foo", action: "bar", method: :post) do %>
  <%= fields_for(:subscriber, @user) do |sub_fields| %>
    <div class="row">
      <%= sub_fields.label :email %>
      <%= sub_fields.text_field :email %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= fields_for(@cat) do |cat_fields| %>
    <div class="row">
      <%= sub_fields.label :name %>
      <%= cat_fields.text_field :name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Lets go over it from the top:

- We use `form_tag` instead of `form_for` since we just want a form that is not bound to a resouce.
- `fields_for` lets us bind inputs to any arbitrary resource.

The resulting params would be somthing like this:

```
{
  subscriber: {
    email: 'john.doe@example.com'
  },
  cat: {
    name: 'Nisse'
  }
}
```

See also:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Thank you. That worked! I just had to add a submit_tag and get the syntax correct in the form_tag and fields_for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the fields_for wrapper.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for